# Can't connect to WiFi network

Tags: wireless, broadcom, raspberrypi

I just installed Ubuntu via the Raspberry imager, so I was connected to wifi just fine using Raspberry OS on my SD card, but Ubuntu is telling me keys are required and it's not getting connected.

When I try to connect via the cli I get the following error message.

```
Error: Connection activation failed: Secrets were required, but not provided.
```

[wireless]
vendor Broadcom
no soft blocked

[image]

Comment: By "Passwords or Encryption keys" it means the password for the network.

Comment: Enter the wifi password

Comment: wow lol of course that's what I'm doing... what could be going wrong? why I try to connect via the cli I get Error: Connection activation failed: Secrets were required, but not provided.

Answer (score 1):

The Authentication required window is prompting you to enter the password for the wireless network. Enter the wifi password for PIANO108, so that you can connect to the internet via this available network's wifi.

Sometimes restarting the NetworkManager service can resolve temporary glitches. Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

If this doesn't work, check the systemd logs of the current boot for NetworkManager for any additional clues. Open the terminal and run:

```
journalctl -b | grep NetworkManager
```

This will show logs in real time. Look for entries that were logged at the same time that you tried connecting.

Comment: wow lol of course that's what I'm doing... what could be going wrong? why I try to connect via the cli I get 
Error: Connection activation failed: Secrets were required, but not provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you using a monitor with 2560x1440 resolution at 60Hz, try a different resolution or refresh rate. That particular one seems to interfere with WiFi connections, either making authentication impossible (keeps asking for password) or making the connection very unstable.